Upgrading Oracle Database from 11g to 23AI FREE and cannot log on from application
I'm upgrading my Oracle Database from 11g to 23AI FREE, got all my data, procedures, functions, packages and user accounts/information migrated from the 11g database to the 23AI database and I'm able to connect to the 23AI database using one of my normal user accounts with Sql Developer, but unable to connect using that same account information with my application.  Same username and password, so I know it's valid but I get the error message:
ORA-01017: invalid credential or not authorized; logon denied

I'm obviously able to get to the database, but for some reason it's saying that the same credentials that I use to connect with Sql, Developer are not valid.  I'm confused, am I missing something?
This is the connection string I'm using in my app:
"Data Source=FREE;User ID=myuser;password=password1"

This is the code:
   Dim ConnObject As New OracleConnection
   ConnObject.ConnectionString = "Data Source=FREE;User ID=myuser;password=password1"
   ConnObject.Open()

With Sql Developer I needed to execute the command Alter Session set container = freepdb1 before logging on as the application user, everything I've read online about 23AI says that I don't need to do that with an app created with Visual Studio, in this case Visual Studio 2017.  The app functions flawlessly on the 11G database, so I know the app is good.  Am I missing something here?  Is there a new step I got to take that I didn't need when connecting to the 11g database?
This is my listener.ora for 23AI:
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = FREE
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

This is the tnsnames.ora:
DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = FREE)
    )
  )
FREE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = FREE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_FREE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

I added the Data entry myself, that is the entry I used in the connection string on the 11g database, so I added it here so I could just copy over the app and it would connect, but it didn't turn out that way.  Whatever entry I use I get the same error, ORA-01017: invalid credential or not authorized; logon denied.  So either way, I'm able to get to the database, the database says my credentials aren't valid, yet I can connect using Sql Developer with the same username and password.  I'm baffled.

if the service name is freepdb1 the tnsnames.ora should not try to connect to one named FREE...

The service name is NOT freepdb1, that's the container.

Which OracleConnection do you use, i..e which namespace? Which Oracle driver/provider do you use and which version? What is version 11g? 11.1 or 11.2?

@Wernfried Domscheit I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v21.14.0

Hard to believe, that is works with Oracle 11, because you cannot connect with an Oracle 21 client to an Oracle 11 database, see Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions

Well, it does.  I noticed that the version I'm,using is an older version, I'm upgrading to the latest, v23.6.1.  We'll see what happens.

@Wernfried Domscheit Now that I think about it, I remembered that any version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess greater than v21.14.0 would NOT connect to the 11g database, that's why I was using that particular version.

@PrescottChartier I think there is some confusion about the CDB and PDB. Your application should almost certainly connect to the PDB directly and not the CDB. The default configuration is that the service name matches the PDB name, so it really seems like you should be connecting to "freepdb1" instead of "free".

@Jon Heller No, using FREEPDB1 generates ORA-12154: Cannot connect to database. Cannot find alias FREEPDB1 in DataSources,.  Using FREE I can connect to the database, I just cannot log on using the users credentials even though those credentials work in Sql Developer.

@Wernfried Domscheit
Upgrading to the latest version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess did not change anything.  Same error.

@Wernfried Domschei When I execute select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME='MyUser' Sql Developer returns zero rows.  Same thing for select * from USER_TAB_PRIVS where Grantee = 'MyUser' and select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME = 'MyUser'.  Yet when I scroll down and expand other users then right click on MyUser, it says that the user has Connect, Create Session, and the role I defined for my users.  What is that all about?

@PrescottChartier User names are case insensitive when you log in, but they are stored as upper case in the data dictionary. Try 'MYUSER' instead.

Already tried that, Upper/lower case made no difference.

I suspect You are using the 23ai FREE from the docker container.
Different from 11g, 23ai FREE has a multitenant architecture and the one on the docker container has a root container database (CDB) using service FREE, and one pluggable database (PDB) where your normal user accounts should be using service FREEPDB1.
These services should look like this in tnsnames.ora:
FREE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = FREE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_FREE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


FREEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = FREEPDB1)
    )
  )

Change the the connection string you are using in your app to:
"Data Source=FREEPDB1;User ID=myuser;password=password1"


Same result, invalid credential or not authorized; logon denied.  I'm thinking that there is something I missed setting up the database.  Not authorized is what I'm focusing on right now.  I know the username and password is correct.  I can't log on as the user with SqlPlus either, only Sql Developer.  This is all very baffling.
